# Left join same table twice but one column is repeat

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The main table want to join two time with the reffrence table twice with the same column.
The main table column is insert with integer and need to join with the refference table to get the character back to show back for user.
it show none of records by the sql below, why?

main table `BD_BRAND`

```
Sports_BR  Leather_BR
   2          1
```

Reffrence table `BD_REF`

```
ID   NME         REF_TYPE
1    NIKE      Sports_Brand
2    ADIDAS    Sports_Brand
3    PUMA      Sports_Brand
1    CLACKS    Leather_Brand
2    LOTTUSSE  Leather_Brand
3    CHEANEY   Leather_Brand





   SELECT B.NME AS Sports_BR, C.NME AS Leather_BR  
    FROM BD_BRAND A
    LEFT JOIN BD_REF B on B.ID =  A.Sports_BR  
    LEFT JOIN BD_REF C on C.ID =  A.Leather_BR
```

The Result i want as below:

```
Sports_BR  Leather_BR
 ADIDAS     CLACKS
```

Comment: You haven't joined `BD_BRAND` (`A` alias) to anything. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @BobJarvis i have edit the question, i put the wrong join.

Comment: @BobJarvis Leather_BR is 4, i just edit it.

Comment: What result is your query returning?

Comment: @BobJarvis Leather_BR is change to 1 because the id will repeat in table ref

Comment: @result return an empty table

Comment: It works fine for me. [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9a139/1) - which uses SQLite (which is the only thing that still works at SQLFiddle - feh) but the database engine shouldn't matter - this is a very basic query that any relational database should process in the same manner. The only possibility I can think of is that SQL Server may not like the column rename, so try changing the first line to `SELECT B.NME AS Sports_BR_NAME, C.NME AS Leather_BR_NAME`. Best of luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145832/discussion-between-andrew-madman-and-bob-jarvis).

Comment: @BobJarvis it seen the same no records show

Comment: BTW, why don't you explain the logic behind the output desire ?Or why don't you give another example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT B.NME AS Sports_BR, C.NME AS Leather_BR  
FROM BD_BRAND A
LEFT JOIN BD_REF B on B.ID =  A.Sports_BR and B.REF_TYPE = 'Sports_Brand' 
LEFT JOIN BD_REF C on C.ID =  A.Leather_BR and B.REF_TYPE = 'Leather_Brand'
```

Your ID's are present multiple times due to the different reference types, so you need to specify which ID to grab by the reference type.

Comment: @AndrewMadMan Glad I could help :)